# Google Spreadsheet - Use a cell to get another cell last time update date

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I just started using Google Sheets and I'm having trouble when setting a script.
I need a cell (let's say "AF4") to get the last modification date of another cell (let's say "X4").
Here's my script so far:

```
`function onEdit(e)
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editRow = editRange.getRow();
var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange("X4");
var rangeRow = range.getRow();
var rangeCol = range.getColumn();
if (editRow = rangeRow && editCol = rangeCol)
  {
  sheet.getRange("AF4").setValue(new Date());
  }
}`
```

When I try to save it, it says "invalid transfer on left side, line 1, "code" "
I'd really apprecite any help with that.
Thank you,
CURTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your condition seems to be wrong, that's why the error appears :)

`if (editRow = rangeRow && editCol = rangeCol)`

in case you want to check based on more conditions, the syntax must be

```
if (condition) {
 block of code to be executed if the condition is true
if (condition) {
block of code to be executed if the condition is true
 }
}`
```

I modified a bit of your code that you get an idea, of what needs to be done in order to achieve your goal, this script to get the last modification date of column X and post "new date" into AF4 (so whenever you edit something on column "x" and the row 4 the date will be set in AF4)

```
 function onEdit() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
 var editRow = editRange.getRow();
 var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
 var editCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var range = sheet.getRange("X4");
 var rangeRow = range.getRow();
 var rangeCol = range.getColumn();
 if( sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
if( editCell.getColumn() == 24 ) { //checks that we're on the correct column ; column x = 24
  if( editCell.getRow() == 4 ) { //checks that we're on the correct row ; row 4 = 4
    sheet.getRange("AF4").setValue(new Date());
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Data changed', 'Info', 2); //give a Info, that something was done correctly
  }
 }
}
}
```

Hope this will help you!

**EDIT**

**Script from comments request, whenever something on Column X is changed, add Date to column AF in the same row**

```
function onEdit() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange(); 
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn(); 
  var editCell = sheet.getActiveCell(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("X4"); 
  if( editCell.getColumn() == 24 ) { 
    var rangeCol = range.getColumn();
    var editRow = editRange.getRow(); 
    sheet.getRange(editRow,rangeCol+8).setValue(new Date()); //use the RangeCol + 8 Columns 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Date added', 'Info', 2); //this line can be deleted 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
It helped a lot, even being only the start of my script.
What I really need is that the script check last modification date in each row of column X and write down this date on each row of column AF, in each respective row.

Comment: don't forget to accept my answer ;) anyway here is the script then:

function onEdit() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
 var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
 var editCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var range = sheet.getRange("X4");
 if( editCell.getColumn() == 24 ) {
   var rangeCol = range.getColumn();
   var editRow = editRange.getRow();
    sheet.getRange(editRow,rangeCol+8).setValue(new Date()); //use the RangeCol + 8 Columns
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Date added', 'Info', 2); //this line can be deleted
 }
}

Comment: Thank you again, it helped a lot :)
Answer accepted!